# How to Download Website generated report in webview (PDF File) Website generate report using report engine

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I am loading a website in webview.

If url is with extension .pdf then this pdf file gets downloaded.

But in my case, website generates a PDF file using report engine plugin .So how download this generated report?

**This report download works in browser but inside webview its not working.**

```
 public void downloadFiles(WebView view) {
        view.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }


        });
    }
```

### this code downloads PDF file if URL extension is .PDF but generated report does not downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You could override [WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) .

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  {

    if(url.contains(".pdf") { 

          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i);
          return true;
    } else {  
         return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Savin first thank you for answer. But if url extension .PDF then file download work perfect. But thai report generated using report engine. So not getting any url extension with .pdf.